# asp.net update table on click of a button

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am new to asp.net and stuck at a very stupid problem. But I cannot figure it out. I have a form which is filled by data from DB on page_load, and user update the form's input's text and click the "update" button. It updates but it updates with old data.

WHY DOES IT UPDATE IT WITH OLD DATA?

here is the aspx form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="lbl_id" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FirstName</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_firstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LastName</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_lastname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is the code behind

```
protected void Guncelle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DbCommand dbCommand;
        dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("MedBul_Update_Registration_Request");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "id", DbType.Int16, request_id);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "FirstName", DbType.String, txt_firstname.Text.ToString().Trim());
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "LastName", DbType.String, txt_lastname.Text.ToString().Trim());
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
 }
```

here is the stored procedure

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[MedBul_Update_Registration_Request]
(@id int,@FirstName varchar(50),@LastName varchar(50))

    AS
    BEGIN

    update NewProfessionalRequest set FirstName= @FirstName, LastName =@LastName
     where id = @id

    END

    GO
```

Comment: Please add the content of your stored procedure.

Comment: what do you see in txt_firstname.Text when you click on button Guncelle again in debug mode?

Comment: it displays the new data.

Comment: show us the stored procedure. I think issue is there

Comment: which version of .net you use?

Comment: check if you are getting same id  in request_id every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you filling page controls with data on page load.
Wrap your code on Page_Load like this:

```
if(!isPostBack)
{
    // populate form with data from DB here
}
```

Because when you hitting UpdateBtn Page_Load event is being fired and your changes being re-writed with 'old' data from DB.

Answer (score 1):

You should check Page.IsPostBack Property on page load.

See following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Comment: I am using if(!isPostBack)