# data is not updating in database asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Did not find any error but data is not updating in database and displaying error on first load is

> There is no row at position 0

and data displaying in gridview below.

But when load from menu data is displaying in textbox's.

Update Button Code

```
Protected Sub taxsubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles taxsubmit.Click
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Deduction] SET [IncomeTax] = @IncomeTax, [SalesTax] = @SalesTax, [ServiceTax] = @ServiceTax, [LabourCess] = @LabourCess, [SocityTax] = @SocityTax, [ESIC] = @ESIC, [EPF] = @EPF, [Security] = @Security, [FinYear] = @FinYear, [Condition1] = @Condition1, [Condition2] = @Condition2, [Condition3] = @Condition3, [CompID] = " + Session("Companydetl") + " WHERE [DedID] = " + dedid + ""
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncomeTax", Income_Tax.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesTax", Sales.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceTax", Service.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabourCess", Labour_Cess.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocityTax", Society.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ESIC", ESIC.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EPF", EPF.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Security", Security.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinYear", Fin_Year.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition1", Cond1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition2", Cond2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition3", Cond3.Text)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Data Display Code

```
Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = "Select DedID, IncomeTax, SalesTax, ServiceTax, LabourCess, SocityTax, ESIC, EPF, 
                                    Security, FinYear, Condition1, Condition2, Condition3 from Deduction where CompID = '" + Session("Companydetl") + "'"
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                con.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Try
                    dt.Load(reader)
                    Income_Tax.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("IncomeTax").ToString.Trim()
                    Labour_Cess.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("LabourCess").ToString.Trim()
                    ESIC.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("ESIC").ToString.Trim()
                    EPF.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("EPF").ToString.Trim()
                    Society.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("SocityTax").ToString.Trim()
                    Service.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("ServiceTax").ToString.Trim()
                    Sales.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("SalesTax").ToString.Trim()
                    Security.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Security").ToString.Trim()
                    Fin_Year.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("FinYear").ToString.Trim()
                    Cond1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Condition1").ToString.Trim()
                    Cond2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Condition2").ToString.Trim()
                    Cond3.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Condition3").ToString.Trim()
                    dedid = dt.Rows(0).Item("DedID").ToString.Trim()
                    con.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message, vbOKOnly, "Error")
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
```

[Image on direct load of page after login.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Aid.jpg)

[Image After loading page from the above menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2cSs.jpg)

as am new to this please help.

Comment: In your `Click` event handler, where are you setting the value of `dedid`? That's the first place I'd look; if your query isn't returning any results, there's no record to update. Also, your SQL statement is vulnerable to an injection attack. You'll want to use query parameters for the entire statement, not just most of it.

Comment: I set the value on command for updating the data. And please help me for prevent from SQL injection. Suggest the way for that. Please

Comment: SQL Injection: You're almost there. Add parameters for the last two columns in your statement, `[CompID]` and `[DedID]`. Concatenating the string as you are now creates the vulnerability. Search: [Prevent SQL Injection](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=prevent+sql+injection)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you've created `dedid` as a field or a property in the class. Your problem is likely occurring because values for those don't persist between page loads.

Try storing it in a `Session` variable as you are with `CompID`.

Comment: Set a break in your `Click` event handler, step through the code and make sure that `dedid` contains the value that you expect it to. Further, while debugging, build the SQL statement in a text editor and run it directly against the database (using SSMS or a similar tool). See whether your .NET code is sending the correct SQL statement to the database.

Comment: i tried it in SQL Query and query executed successfully with data and even on the GRIDVIEW on the page; Data is displaying.

Comment: @AtulSharma — Did you manually construct your SQL update statement while in debugger break mode in your `Click` event handler? Can you verify that there is indeed a row in your database containing the value in the `[DedID]` column that equals the value in your `dedid` variable?

Comment: @AtulSharma — Here's your update statement: `UPDATE [Deduction] SET [IncomeTax] = @IncomeTax, [SalesTax] = @SalesTax, [ServiceTax] = @ServiceTax, [LabourCess] = @LabourCess, [SocityTax] = @SocityTax, [ESIC] = @ESIC, [EPF] = @EPF, [Security] = @Security, [FinYear] = @FinYear, [Condition1] = @Condition1, [Condition2] = @Condition2, [Condition3] = @Condition3, [CompID] = @Companydetl WHERE [DedID] = @dedid`. Using your text editor, replace `@IncomeTax` with the value in `Income_Tax.Text`, `@SalesTax` with that of `Sales.Text`, and so on. Run that against your database and see what you get.

Comment: @AtulSharma — Better yet, scrap the manual SQL and switch to Entity Framework. EF builds all your parameterized queries for you, enabling you to concentrate on solving the business problem at hand instead of mucking about with the plumbing as you are now.

Comment: as am new can you please help me for that. Entity Framework is fresh new chapter for me.

Comment: @AtulSharma — Try [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/).

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to Entity Framework, your code will look something like this:

```
Using oDb As New MyDbContext(ConnectionString)
  Dim oDeduction as Deduction

  oDeduction = oDb.Deductions.Where(Function(D) D.DedID = dedid).Single
  oDeduction.IncomeTax = Income_Tax.Text
  oDeduction.SalesTax = Sales.Text
  oDeduction.ServiceTax = Service.Text
  oDeduction.LabourCess = Labour_Cess.Text
  oDeduction.SocityTax = Society.Text
  oDeduction.ESIC = ESIC.Text
  oDeduction.EPF = EPF.Text
  oDeduction.Security = Security.Text
  oDeduction.FinYear = Fin_Year.SelectedValue
  oDeduction.Condition1 = Cond1.Text
  oDeduction.Condition2 = Cond2.Text
  oDeduction.Condition3 = Cond3.Text

  oDb.SaveChanges()
End Using
```

Note that I just hammered this together by memory in TextPad — it's untested and syntax may not be exactly correct. It's just a sample of the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support but I found my point

```
If Session("login") = Nothing Then
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
        Session.Abandon()
        Session.RemoveAll()
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
    ElseIf Not IsPostBack Then
        Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Deduction where CompID = '" + Session("Companydetl") + "'"
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                con.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Try
                    dt.Load(reader)
                    Income_Tax.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("IncomeTax").ToString.Trim()
                    Labour_Cess.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("LabourCess").ToString.Trim()
                    ESIC.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("ESIC").ToString.Trim()
                    EPF.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("EPF").ToString.Trim()
                    Society.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("SocityTax").ToString.Trim()
                    Service.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("ServiceTax").ToString.Trim()
                    Sales.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("SalesTax").ToString.Trim()
                    Security.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Security").ToString.Trim()
                    Fin_Year.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("FinYear").ToString.Trim()
                    Cond1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Condition1").ToString.Trim()
                    Cond2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Condition2").ToString.Trim()
                    Cond3.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Condition3").ToString.Trim()
                    'Session("deductionid") = dt.Rows(0).Item("DedID").ToString.Trim()
                    con.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message, vbOKOnly, "Error")
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
```

when i add "Not IsPostBack" then all the data is updating and the working thanks all for the support
found at [Post Back Error Same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382090/asp-net-update-table-on-click-of-a-button)

Thank You All

Update Button

```
Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Deduction SET IncomeTax=" + Income_Tax.Text + ", SalesTax=" + Sales.Text + ", ServiceTax=" + Service.Text + ", LabourCess=" + Labour_Cess.Text + ", 
              SocityTax=" + Society.Text + ", ESIC=" + ESIC.Text + ", EPF=" + EPF.Text + ", Security=" + Security.Text + ", FinYear=" + Fin_Year.SelectedValue + ", 
              Condition1='" + Cond1.Text + "', Condition2='" + Cond2.Text + "', Condition3='" + Cond3.Text + "' WHERE CompID = " + Session("Companydetl") + ""
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, vbOKOnly, "Error")
            End Try
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
```